# Incorrect behaviour during scrolling, that shows shows up depending on how the code is linked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a real problem coming up with a good title, i have tried my best.

The problem starts when i try to experiment with adding material to the bottom of the page. I have tried the following on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LLw1hs4r/1/), and it works! When i scroll down new `<div>`s are generated just fine, and they are generated when/where necessary.

So i attempt to do it without jsfiddle, and put the code all in one page:

```
<html>
<meta>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
                        var a = $('<a class="post" href="?">');
                        a.append('<div class="name_of_post">TITLE</div>');
                        a.append('<div class="descriptioin_of_post">DESCRIPTION</div>');
                        $('a.post').last().after(a);
                        console.log($(document).height(), $(window).scrollTop(), $(window).height());
   }
     });
});
  </script>
  <style>
.post{
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 49%;
        height: 150px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 2%;
        background-color: #FFF;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 1px 1px 3px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        -moz-user-select: none; 
        -webkit-user-select: none; 
        -ms-user-select:none;
        user-select:none;
        -o-user-select:none;
        transition: outline 0.3s; 
        text-decoration: none;
        outline: solid 5px transparent;
}
.post:hover{
        outline: solid 5px #fc490a;
}
.post:first-child{
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
}
.post:nth-child(2){
        margin-top: 0
}
.post:nth-child(2n+1){
        margin-left: 0;
}
.img_of_post{
        position: absolute;
        left:0px;
        width: 35%;
        top: 0px;
}
.name_of_post{
        font-family: SegoeUIRegular;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
        color:black;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
        margin-left: 36.5%;
        line-height: 23px;
}
.descriptioin_of_post{
        font-family: SegoeUIRegular;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 13px;
        color:#666666;
        margin-left: 36.5%;
        line-height: 17px;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 <a class='post' href='.'>
    <div class='name_of_post'>OLD DIV</div>
    <div class='description_of_post'>old description</div>
 </a>
 <a class='post' href='.'>
    <div class='name_of_post'>OLD DIV</div>
    <div class='description_of_post'>old description</div>
 </a>
 <a class='post' href='.'>
    <div class='name_of_post'>OLD DIV</div>
    <div class='description_of_post'>old description</div>
 </a>
 <a class='post' href='.'>
    <div class='name_of_post'>OLD DIV</div>
    <div class='description_of_post'>old description</div>
 </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note, that it is the exact same code as is on jsfiddle, with only some differences (added `<html>` tag, built-in css into the page and added script tags manually).

And here the problem starts, for some reason new `<div>`s are generated only when i scroll up. In other words i need to be scrolling up and hit the top, rather than scrolling down and hitting the bottom.

Why is this happening in the single page HTML code? What do i need to do for this to work the same way as in JSFiddle?

Comment: put your style code in head tag in html , paste your script code below html close tag

Comment: try adding few more `<a class='post' href='.'>
    <div class='name_of_post'>OLD DIV</div>
    <div class='description_of_post'>old description</div>
 </a>`

then its working... I gues since when you open the html document in browser we cant scroll down and hence its not working...

Comment: also change 
`if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {`
to
`if($(window).scrollTop()  == ($(document).height() -  $(window).height())) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace in your code:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
```

to

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight == $(document).height()) {
```

Comment: Wow, this worked, but could you explain what it did?

Comment: You wont believe!!!!!!


I just added "<!DOCTYPE html>" in your original code and it worked!!! hahahaha

Answer (score 1):

When there is no scrollbar your code doesnt work.. I have added mousewheel event kindly try the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<meta>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop()  == ($(document).height() -  $(window).height())) {
                        var a = $('<a class="post" href="?">');
                        a.append('<div class="name_of_post">TITLE</div>');
                        a.append('<div class="descriptioin_of_post">DESCRIPTION</div>');
                        $('a.post').last().after(a);
                        console.log($(document).height(), $(window).scrollTop(), $(window).height());
   }


     });
     $(document).on('mousewheel', function(e){
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 < 0) {

         if ($("body").height()< $(window).height()) {
        var a = $('<a class="post" href="?">');
                        a.append('<div class="name_of_post">TITLE</div>');
                        a.append('<div class="descriptioin_of_post">DESCRIPTION</div>');
                        $('a.post').last().after(a);
                        console.log($(document).height(), $(window).scrollTop(), $(window).height());
         }
      }

});
});
  </script>
  <style>
.post{
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 49%;
        height: 150px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 2%;
        background-color: #FFF;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 1px 1px 3px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        -moz-user-select: none; 
        -webkit-user-select: none; 
        -ms-user-select:none;
        user-select:none;
        -o-user-select:none;
        transition: outline 0.3s; 
        text-decoration: none;
        outline: solid 5px transparent;
}
.post:hover{
        outline: solid 5px #fc490a;
}
.post:first-child{
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
}
.post:nth-child(2){
        margin-top: 0
}
.post:nth-child(2n+1){
        margin-left: 0;
}
.img_of_post{
        position: absolute;
        left:0px;
        width: 35%;
        top: 0px;
}
.name_of_post{
        font-family: SegoeUIRegular;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
        color:black;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
        margin-left: 36.5%;
        line-height: 23px;
}
.descriptioin_of_post{
        font-family: SegoeUIRegular;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 13px;
        color:#666666;
        margin-left: 36.5%;
        line-height: 17px;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

 <a class='post' href='.'>
    <div class='name_of_post'>OLD DIV</div>
    <div class='description_of_post'>old description</div>
 </a>
 <a class='post' href='.'>
    <div class='name_of_post'>OLD DIV</div>
    <div class='description_of_post'>old description</div>
 </a>
 <a class='post' href='.'>
    <div class='name_of_post'>OLD DIV</div>
    <div class='description_of_post'>old description</div>
 </a>


</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: Thanks. It does add them faster than i can scroll with a mousewheel, and it resolves a different problem. Still a good addition to my knowledge!